# name list in PostgreSQL 13.0

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-13

list the name autors with the first name chris by alfabetic order

Tabela ESTRELAS
Nome da coluna  Tipo    Descrição
id  INTEGER id do gênero
nome_estrela    VARCHAR Nome da estrela de cinema (atores e atrizes)

```
SELECT nome_estrela
FROM ESTRELAS
WHERE nome_estrela IN (SELECT split_part('', 'nome_estrelas', 00.)
                       FROM ESTRELAS
                      ORDER BY nome_estrela ASC
                      WHERE nome_estrela ( SELECT split_part('nome_estrela', ' ', 00.) 
                                               FROM ESTRELAS
                                               WHERE nome_estrela LIKE 'Chris%'
                                              )
                       );
```

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/sequel-5.47.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:156:in `exec': PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 13:                       WHERE nome_estrela ( SELECT split_part...
                               ^
 (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

list the chris last names by asc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to list the names where the first name is Chris in alphabetical order and `nome_estrela` is the column containing the full name, the following should work:

```
SELECT nome_estrela
FROM ESTRELAS
WHERE nome_estrela LIKE 'Chris%'
ORDER BY nome_estrela ASC
```

`ASC` here is optional for documentation purposes, as that is the default sorting order. So `ORDER BY nome_estrela` does exactly the same as `ORDER BY nome_estrela ASC`.

Comment: Good point, added some clarification on that.